# Show that in every plane parallel to X-Y plane the equipotential lines are circle

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

I found this question in the book for IIT JEE by DC Pandey. I doubt that some information must be given about the electric field before asking this question?
Please help if you get this question.

Comment: This question can not be understood without more information,

Comment: @trula yeah, even i was doubting that. Thanks for help!